# Datasource configurations compatible with JBOSS versions

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jboss5.x, jboss-4.2.x

There are couple of  datasource configuration files for XA and NON-XA datasource in JBOSS v4.2.3 for the various need of the deployed applications in the jboss environment. Also the DB passwords are encrypted using the JBOSS provided techniques (some datasources are created using JaasSecurityDomain and some use SecureIdentityLoginModule) .

How these datasource configurations and these encryption methodologies are going to behave in jboss v5 and jbossv7 ?

Is there any JBOSS tool/utility to convert the datasource to the corresponding new JBOSS version and also take care of the encryption password part ?

What is the best way to migrate these datasources created with the password encrypted.

Any help in this topic is highly appreciated .

Regards,

Jiten

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Windup project http://windup.jboss.org/

that is aiming to provide as automated upgrade as possible.